# iWork - causing issues on index.html file

Tags: php, html, parsing, syntax

Problem:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/brofesso/public_html/brofessor.org/index.html on line 1

Line 1:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url= www.brofessor.org/Velkommen.html" /></head><body></body></html>
```

I'm fairly new to this; and I'm trying to learn how to add my own webpage through iWork.

I just added the standard page, but I always get that issue. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Hint: when you have an error message about a "line", you'd do better to put fewer things on the "line".

Comment: Does '<?xml' start at column 1?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/brofesso/public_html/index.html on line 1

Comment: thats the error I get whenever I publish the page.

Comment: FYI,  you should have used the "PHP" tag if you're working with PHP. It likely makes a big difference. Try the HTML I used below, and please report the error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/brofesso/public_html/test/index.html on line 1

Thats what I got again. Created a test page and used what you suggested. Still the same error.

Comment: Like I asked, does your first line start in column 1?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer; it's a formatted comment. Try the following and then report the line number of the error, if any:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url= www.brofessor.org/Velkommen.html"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem Solved! iWork is just plane broken. It turned out that everything written and added in iWork will be twisted and distorted when published. Purchased Sandvox instead.